# Topology on Integers such that set of all Primes is open

Tags: general-topology, prime-numbers

In my topology homework we are asked to describe a topology on the Integers such that:

1. set of all Primes is open.
2. for each $x\in\mathbb Z$, the set $\{x\}$ is not open.
3. $\forall x,y \in\mathbb Z$ distinct, there is an open $U\ni x$ and an open $V\ni y$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$

i was looking at Furstenberg's topology as in [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_Proof_of_Infinitude_of_Primes) proof:
For $m, b \in\mathbb Z$ with $m > 0$ define $N(m,b):=\{mx + b : x ∈ Z\}$, an arithmetic progression streching towards infinity in both directions. A set $U$ is open if either:

1. $U = \emptyset$; or
2. For each $b\in U$ there is an $m>0$ such that $N(m,b)\subseteq U$.

but as I understand the set of Primes is not open in this topology. Now I'm not sure what should I do: is there a way to modify this topology to make set of Primes open or should I think of something completely different.

Any hints are appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: An idea for you to try: define a base (or perhaps subbase...?) for the wanted topology with sets that contain an infinite number of primes. If this possibly generates a topology then the set of all primes would be open, but I can't say off the top of my head whether it'd fulfill the other requirements

Comment: The above won't work: the intersection of two such sets could have *a finite* number of primes (zero primes is fine and can fit within the definition if we add it, say for the empty set). Perhaps the topology resulting from requiring that *the complement* of a set contains a finite number of primes would work?

Comment: This won't work either, because the complement of $\{p\}$ for any prime $p$ would have to be open, so that $\{p\}$ is open itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cheap way to go about it is the following:

1. Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers, and $\mathbb{P}^\prime = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \mathbb{P}$.
2. As both $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}^\prime$ are countably infinite, pick bijections $f : \mathbb{P} \to \mathbb{Q}$, $g : \mathbb{P}^\prime \to \mathbb{Q}$.
3. Define $U \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ to be open iff $f [ U \cap \mathbb{P} ]$ and $g [ U \cap \mathbb{P}^\prime ]$ are both open subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ (under the subspace topology).

Comment: @Torben: $\mathbb{Q}$ is given the topology it inherits as a _subspace_ of $\mathbb{R}$: $U \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is open iff there is an open $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $U = W \cap \mathbb{Q}$.